Refinitiv Codebook Python Data Retrieval limit
how do i get the second 10,000 cusips from the US municipal universe from Refinitiv using Python and Refinitiv's Codebook.
import refinitiv.data as rd

rd.open_session()

response = rd.discovery.search( view=rd.discovery.Views.MUNICIPAL_INSTRUMENTS, top=20000, skip = 10000, filter=(IsActive eq true and SearchAllCategoryv2 eq 'US Municipal Bonds'), select=CUSIP ) 

This call fails with this message: RDError: Error code 400 | Validation error: json.Top in body should be less than or equal to 10000
Is there a way around this limit of 10,000?
